# How to execute a command in CodeMirror-ui using Angular?

Tags: angularjs, codemirror, ui-codemirror

In codemirror-ui I want to execute one of the commands described here:
https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#commands

I have the following code:

```
<ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions" ng-model="model"/>
<input type="button" ng-click="selectAll()" value="Select All"/>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.selectAll = new function() {
    // how to cm.execCommand('selectAll')?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To execute command or executed any method in codemirror using angularjs , you have to select the instance of the codemirror, something like this.

var codeMirrorInstance = angular.element('#idCodemirror').CodeMirror;

after that do you have access over all that method

```
codeMirrorInstance.refresh();

codeMirrorInstance.setSelection( {line: codeMirrorInstance.firstLine(), ch: 0},  {line: codeMirrorInstance.lastLine()+1, ch: 0});
```